# forcing iframe submit to open in parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, submit, parent

I am trying to embed a form on my wix website. The idea is that when someone submits the form, a "thank you" page will be displayed instead of the original parent page. Right now, the way the code is written, the "thank you" page is displayed upon submit, but is shown within the iframe, with scrolls up/down and to the sides. I want to force the "thank you" page to be displayed out of the iframe.
I'm a novice to coding, so I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what code I should enter and where in the code it should go. I've included the original code of the form.

Thanks in advance,
Anat

```
<!-- AT Popup Beta 2017 BEGIN -->
<link href="//cdn-media.web-view.net/popups/style/v1/main_combined.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="_atPopupSU" class="shown"><div class="bl-template row-fluid bl-content-removable popup-dir-ltr" id="template-body" data-page-width="383" data-new-from-template="false">     <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE OUTER -->     <div class="bl-template-main-wrapper span12" id="bl_0" valign="top">        <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE MARGIN (Outside Margin - Padding) -->        <div class="bl-template-margin span12" id="bl_1" valign="top">            <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE WRAPPER (Background) -->            <div class="template-main-table bl-template-background span12" id="bl_2" valign="top">                <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE CONTAINER (Border, Inner Padding) -->                <div class="bl-template-border span12" id="bl_3" valign="top">                    <!-- BEGIN ZONES CONTAINER -->                    <!--zone-marked-->                    <div class="bl-zone bl-zone-dropable bl-zone-body row-fluid" id="bl_4" style="margin-top: 0px !important; background-color: transparent;" name="BodyZone" valign="top" height="">                   <div class="bl-block bl-block-signuptextpage" id="bl_5" blocktype="signuptextpage" name="signuptextpage" style="width: 383px;"><div class="bl-block-content" contenteditable="false"> <div> <div class="bl-block-content-table bl-block-dir-ltr span12"> <div class="bl-block-content-row bl-block-content-first-row bl-block-content-last-row span12" style="border-radius: 10px;"> <div class="bl-block-content-row-inner span12" style="padding: 50px 20px 18px;"><div class="bl-block-content-column bl-block-content-new-column span12"><div class="bl-padding-columns bl-content-wrapper span12"> <div class="bl-signup-container pull-left span12" at-form-width="12" style="border: 0px solid #191919; border-radius: 5px; padding: 8px 10px; background-color: transparent;">  <div class="bl-block-content-item bl-block-content-item-signupfieldpage bl-content-item-unremovable fields-left" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 14px;" data-is-auto-fill="true"><input type="text" maxlength="50" class="signup-field span12 input-ltr first-input" readonly="readonly" data-field-type="email" data-field-source="Email" data-mandatory="true" placeholder="Email " data-field-validation-msg="This is not a valid email" style="font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 14px; height: 30px; line-height: 12px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left;" data-custom-values="" data-input-type="text"><input type="text" maxlength="50" class="signup-field span12 input-ltr" readonly="readonly" data-field-type="text" data-field-source="Ext1" data-mandatory="false" placeholder="Full Name" data-field-validation-msg="This is not a valid full name" style="font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 14px; height: 30px; line-height: 12px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left;" data-custom-values="" data-input-type="text"><div class="confirm-emails" data-field-validation-msg="Please approve in order to receive our emails" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"> <div class="checkbox ltr"> <label style="cursor: auto;"> <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" style="text-align: left;"><label class="confirm-label dir-label" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; cursor: auto; font-size: 11px; color: #000000;">I approve receiving emails</label></label></div> </div></div> <div class="bl-padding-columns bl-content-wrapper-columns" style="text-align: center;"> <div class="bl-block-button-content-wrapper" style="display: block; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #4ea3a3;"> <div class="bl-block-button-content-item-wrapper" style="font-size: 16px; padding: 9px;"> <div class="bl-block-content-item bl-block-content-item-button bl-content-item-unremovable" style="min-width: 1px; min-height: 16px; display: block; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><strong><span style="color:#FFFFFF;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Sign Up Now</span></span></strong></span></div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div></div></div> </div> </div> </div> </div></div>                     </div>                    <!-- END ZONES CONTAINER -->                </div>                <!-- END TEMPLATE CONTAINER -->            </div>            <!-- END TEMPLATE WRAPPER -->        </div>        <!-- END TEMPLATE MARGIN -->    </div>    <!-- END TEMPLATE OUTER --></div></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function () {
        var _atpopq = window._atpopq || (window._atpopq = []);
        window._atpopobj = {};
        if (!_atpopq.loaded) {
            var atpopjs = document.createElement('script');
            atpopjs.type = 'text/javascript';
            atpopjs.async = true;
            atpopjs.src = '//cdn-media.web-view.net/popups/lib/v1/loader.min.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(atpopjs, s);
            _atpopq.loaded = true;
        }
        _atpopq.push(['UserId', 'zzae3adduwau']);
        _atpopq.push(['PopupId', 'z3zdad']);
        _atpopq.push(['IsraelCode', '104']);
        _atpopq.push(['CountryCode', '226']);
        _atpopq.push(['IsEmbed', true]);
        _atpopq.push(['IgnoreMainCss', true]);
        _atpopq.push(['OnEventCallback', 'handleATPopupEvent']);
    })();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Sample event handler function
    function handleATPopupEvent(ev,args){
        switch(ev){
            case 'display':
                //Do this when the popup is displayed
                break;
            case 'close':
                //Do this when the popup gets closed by the user
                break;
            case 'submit':
                //Do this when popup gets submitted and the user doesn't get redirected to a URL
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- AT Popup Beta END -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this part of code, you should just place the code line:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.yourthankyoupage.com";
```

in case of 'submit'.